# nbsp issue reading XML

Tags: c#, xml

There are several posts on this issue but none of the solutions seem to work for me. Not sure what I'm doing wrong. 
I'm trying to read an XML file that looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<content languageCode="en" languageID="1">
  <ftypeparser>c:\users\pdeoliveira\Documents\Xmlparsernew.xml</ftypeparser>
  <xmlparser>c:\users\pdeoliveira\Documents\Xmlparser.xml</xmlparser>
  <sourcelocation>c:\localization\2015</sourcelocation>
  <rpkfile>RPK_DefaultSyllabi_2015.xml</rpkfile>
  <loglocation>c:\users\pdeoliveira\Documents\Buildloc_Log.txt</loglocation>
  <losefiles><locfile>c:\localization\2015\Strings.xml</locfile></losefiles>
</content>
```

Here's the code that reads it:

```
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        string filetoload = "config.xml";
            try
            {
                doc.Load(filetoload);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
             Console.Writeline(e);
            }
```

And here's the exception I get:

```
System.Xml.XmlException: Reference to undeclared entity 'nbsp'. Line 1960, position 12.
    at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(Exception e)
    at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.HandleGeneralEntityReference(String name,       Boolean isInAttributeValue, Boolean pushFakeEntityIfNullResolver, Int32  entityStartLinePos)
    at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ResolveEntity()
    at System.Xml.XmlLoader.LoadEntityReferenceNode(Boolean direct)
    at System.Xml.XmlLoader.LoadNode(Boolean skipOverWhitespace)
    at System.Xml.XmlLoader.LoadDocSequence(XmlDocument parentDoc)
    at System.Xml.XmlLoader.Load(XmlDocument doc, XmlReader reader, Boolean preserveWhitespace)
    at System.Xml.XmlDocument.Load(XmlReader reader)
    at System.Xml.XmlDocument.Load(String filename)
    at ConsoleApplication9.Program.getrestype(String fname) in  c:\Users\pdeoliveira\Documents\Visual Studio  2013\Projects\BuildLoc\BuildLoc\Program.cs:line 1067
```

I tried using the declaration for nbsp like suggested in other posts:

```
<!DOCTYPE doctypeName [
   <!ENTITY nbsp "&#160;">
]>
```

That didn't work either. The interesting thing is that my file is only 10 or so lines long and it points to an issue on line 1960...??
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The XML you lput in nyour question look like the original. You must put the content of the line is spotted in the error message.

Comment: I did not reproduce the same situation. Everything looks good. Also your xml is well-formatted

Comment: The portion of the xml file you posted looks good.  I would check the entire xml as follows from menu : Project : Add New Item : XML File.  A window will open with the identification xml line.  Paste your xml into window.  The errors will show up in the Error List windows just like any other compiler error.

Comment: @CodeNotFound There is no line 1960 in the file... that's what's puzzling me.

Comment: @jdweng I had tried that already. I did all the obvious things like restarting VS and so on... no clue on what's going on here.

Comment: There's no explicit path on the file name in your code (strFileToLoad). Are you *sure* you're reading the file you think you're reading?

Comment: As stupid as it sounds, I rebooted my machine and i doesn't happen anymore.... I guess I'll never know what happened here. Maybe some other process locking this file like an editor that didn't exit properly... not sure. thanks for your help though!